# PKCS#11 driver for Trusted Platform Module (TPM) chip version 1.2

Tags: linux, ssl, digital-signature, pkcs#11, tpm

I'm building an application can interact with tpm chip via PKCS#11, generate private key (stored in tpm), import certificate which according the private key, sign data,... I want to use tpm chip like a hsm. 
So, someone can help me! What's name of PKCS#11 driver can help me interact with tpm? 
OR What's I must do to make the PKCS#11 driver? I have build OpenCryptoki and Trousers on Centos 6.5 but after build successful I don't know what's file in OpenCrptoki or Trousers is PKCS11 driver!
Thanks!

Comment: The one that the vendor supplies, or else the one supplied by IAIK.

Comment: Hi EJP, What's IAIK? The PKCS#11 driver can be the vendor supplies or build from opensource.

Comment: IAIK is another provider of free PCKS#11 drivers. Try Google. That's how I found it.

Answer (score 0):

[Opencryptoki](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencryptoki/) should support TPM via [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/) (see e.g. [here](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/pkcs11.html), [here](http://www.lorier.net/docs/tpm), [here](https://blog.habets.se/2013/11/TPM-chip-protecting-SSH-keys.html)).

There is a [simple-tpm-pk11 project](https://github.com/ThomasHabets/simple-tpm-pk11) which takes a straighter approach and might be interesting for you -- see [this interesting article on author's blog](https://blog.habets.se/2013/11/TPM-chip-protecting-SSH-keys---properly.html).

Disclaimer: I have never used TPM for doing crypto so please do validate my thoughts.

PS: I forgot to say that opencryptoki PKCS#11 driver usually resides in `/usr/lib/opencryptoki/libopencryptoki.so`.

Comment: Hi, vlp. Thanks! So Can you tell me why I should not use TPM for crypto?

Comment: Hey, I did not say you should not use TPM for crypto -- I just wanted to say that **I** have never used TPM for crypto (I like honesty)...What I do not like about TPM are the measurements, which I fear could be faked with physical access to HW...But I am no TPM expert...Good luck with your project!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood your answer! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi vlp, the openCryptoki can use for Infineon TPM chip? I have installed openCryptoki and try init the chip but it's failed!

Comment: It [should](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Linux+and+Open+Source+activities+for+Trusted+Computing+and+TPM+applications.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b4165abb2043). Did you run `sudo modprobe tpm_tis`? See [this howto](http://joanatrindade.wikidot.com/tpm-howto)...Do you have TPM enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Hi, My pc does not have tpm_tis module. I have loaded tpm_infineon module but when I init it still failed! I have use Centos 6.5. Please see my log here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fniR2RWY_OYm9LNGxYRkFabGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi vlp, I can not load the pkcs11 driver (/usr/lib/opencryptoki/libopencryptoki.so) into Firefox? Do you know how to fix this? thanks!

Comment: modutil -dbdir ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/ -add "TPM" -libfile /usr/lib/opencryptoki/libopencryptoki.so

WARNING: Performing this operation while the browser is running could cause
corruption of your security databases. If the browser is currently running,
you should exit browser before continuing this operation. Type
'q <enter>' to abort, or <enter> to continue:

ERROR: Failed to add module "TPM". Probable cause : "A PKCS #11 module returned CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED, indicating that the requested function could not be performed.  Trying the same operation again might succeed.".

Comment: The error code `0x00000006` given by your `tpmtoken_init` is the same as `CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED` given by the `modutil` tool. Did you call `tpm_takeownership`? It might be a good idea to update your question with new findings -- including which tutorial do you follow and at which step problems appear.

Comment: It is a good idea to try on some newer linux distribution as your CentOS is almost 4 years old...

Comment: And beware that you might lose data if you delete TPM keys you actually use for (e.g. BitLocker encryption in the second OS)

Comment: Hi vlp,
I have tried replace file libopencryptoki.so by cmd line: cp /usr/local/lib/pkcs11/libopencryptoki.so /usr/lib/opencryptoki/libopencryptoki.so
=> the erro fixed. Firefox can load the Pkcs11 module like image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fniR2RWY_OTXFyck5DeUJaLUU/view?usp=sharing
So I have got another error: C_SetPIN failed: 0x00000006 (6). Plz, see here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fniR2RWY_OZ2xMZXJmcDg0Qkk/view?usp=sharing
Currently, my problem is slot can not init! Please hepl me! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of software? If not, use them! Did you see [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/trousers/mailman/message/23508327/)? Are your SRK/owner passwords in line with that? . I am afraid I can't help you any further...And I am sorry for that...Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I have used the lastest version! Many thanks for your help! I will try!